# Widget width variabel price (Shopify)

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I’m about to integrate a Santander widget on my Shopify site, but I need to replace data-amount with price variable: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cf025mnb5lr8j9m/satander_widget.jpg?dl=0

I have tried to use `data-amount="{{current_variant.price}}">` but nofthing happens.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oibwr7qrb20xk33/27.06.2022_19.32.43_REC.png?dl=0

Any idea why it do not works? I'm using current_variant.price others places on the product page

Answer (score 0):

`current_variant` is not a default variable of Shopify. It is something that typicall the theme is setting, somewhere.

You just need to be sure that you're inside the scope of that variable.

Search for `current_variant =`  and you will find where is set, normally this is the value

`{%- assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant -%}`